# Trace div on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I have six floated divs, each with an image as a background. There is a 4.5px margin on each div so it looks like there is a border. 
I want to make it so that on hover, the div's "border" is traced/filled up in a different color. How do I do that?

```
        <div id="one" >
        </div>
        <div id="two" >             
        </div>
        <div id="three" >               
        </div>
        <div id="four" >                
        </div>
        <div id="five" >                
        </div>
        <div id="six" > 
        </div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#one,#two,#three,#four,#five,#six{
max-height:400px;
background-color: grey;
margin:4.5px;   
height:60vh;
width:417px;
max-width:417px;
float:left;
background-size: cover;
opacity:.9;
text-align:center;
}

#one{
background-image:url('../images/1.jpg');
}
#two{
background-image:url('../images/2.jpg');
}
#three{
background-image:url('../images/3.jpg');
}
#four{
background-image:url('../images/4.jpg');
}
#five{
background-image:url('../images/5.jpg');
}
#six{
background-image:url('../images/6.jpg');
}

#one:hover,#two:hover,#three:hover,#four:hover,#five:hover,#six:hover{
opacity:1;
box-shadow:  0 0 0 8px white;
}
```

Comment: You want to create an animated border?

Comment: yes! I want it to be animated

Comment: So which answer solved your problem best? You haven't picked one yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use an svg element instead of a div to animate the border (stroke) using `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray`.

**http://jsfiddle.net/zLuercaa/**

Comment: This looks awesome but I've never used svgs before, is it possible to replace the text with an image?

Answer (score 2):

Make

```
margin:0;
```

and then add a real border to each div

```
border: 4px solid blue;
```

and then on :hover you can change the border color.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `transition-duration: 0.4s;` or whatever time you want to your `div`elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#one,
#two,
#three,
#four,
#five,
#six {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300');
  max-height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 4.5px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 417px;
  max-width: 417px;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .9;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#one:hover,
#two:hover,
#three:hover,
#four:hover,
#five:hover,
#six:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
```